# In Android xml is there a way to have a an object in relative layout fill the remaining space?

Tags: android, xml

I'm a new developer for Android, and I was wondering if there was a way  to have a relative layout object fill the remaining space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on your design don't you have any code for layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relative layout if you define something both above and below the needed object and have the objects location defined as above/next to by both of those it will fill the space between them.